# Adding text box to form

Tags: c#, forms

I am trying to add a dynamic text box to my windows form with the following code. It's all fine up until the last line:

```
Form1.Controls.Add(dynamicTextBox);
```

I'm getting the error:

> "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
> property Control.Controls."

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here and would appreciate any help possible!

```
//create a text box
TextBox dynamicTextBox = new TextBox();

dynamicTextBox.Text = "Text";
dynamicTextBox.Name = "textBox1";
dynamicTextBox.Enabled = false;
dynamicTextBox.Multiline = true;
dynamicTextBox.Height = 80;
dynamicTextBox.Width = 300;
dynamicTextBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(234, 279);

Form1.Controls.add(dynamicTextBox);
```

Comment: 'add' must start with uppercase 'a', Add

Comment: `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property Control.Controls` that error is specifically telling you what is wrong. `add` != `Add` method that add's the control to that collection. Also in your post you do have `Form1.Controls.Add(dynamicTextBox);`, why is it different in the code block you posted; I believe this is just a type-o.

Comment: It won't hurt a litte more of context, so I'm guessing here. Change `Form1.Controls.add` to `Controls.Add`

Comment: It *sounds like* `Form1` is the *class name* - at runtime, you most often use the *object reference* built from that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code adds an text box to the form

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    TextBox txtBox;


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox = new TextBox();
        txtBox.Location = new Point(10, 50);
        txtBox.Visible = true;
        Controls.Add(txtBox);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot! I had the code in the wrong place; moving it fixed that error.

Comment: No problem. Good luck with the project!